# How can I capture input from one keyboard device and prevent it from interacting with other programs?

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey, access-control, proximity

Anyone have a good idea for how to do the following?
I want to capture all input from a specific keyboard device on a Windows machine and prevent it interacting with other programs. I would also like my program not to be in focus if possible.

The device happens to be a USB proximity card reader. I don't want it entering any numbers into a form, I merely want to send it's data to a different application for processing.

I've looked at AutoHotkey and the Python keyboard library and it seems there are ways to do this just wanted to know if anyone had an elegant solution for this already.

Thank you. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Lua Macros is typically better than AHK if you want to differentiate input between different USB devices

Comment: You can use [Interception](http://www.oblita.com/interception). There's a C#/AHK wrapper for it as well called [AutoHotInterception](https://github.com/evilC/AutoHotInterception).